# AWS Automated Patching

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, patch, on-premises-instances

We have onprem servers and EC2 instances. Windows and Linux servers. I've been reading about AWS patch policies and while it seems to automate the process of patching and rebooting servers it doesn't look like it can work on a group of servers and then move on to the next. For example, we tend to patch/reboot the DC servers and when those are done and verfied up and running we move to the SQL servers, then the application servers... But from what I've read patch policies doesn't do this.

I was wondering if anyone has setup server patching automation through AWS and how did they go about it? (Or other tools prefereably free)

Thank you

Comment: From what i understand, you want to follow a multi-step process for the patching. You can use AWS SSM Patch Lifecycle hooks to do the validity. You can have different patching windows for servers so you get some time to validate all changes are in order or not. Refer this blog - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/orchestrating-custom-patch-processes-aws-systems-manager-patch-manager/

and this one - https://dev.to/aws-builders/building-a-patching-model-using-aws-systems-manager-patch-manager-for-mutable-infrastructure-4739